# Why is my class being overwritten?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center-align text by using the bootstrap "text-center" class. I've applied the class to the relevant element, but it's not being rendered appropriately.

My element is defined as follows:

```
<div class="content-panel inline-panel text-center">
    Some text
</div>
```

"inline-panel" does nothing other than applying `display: inline-block;`

As far as I know, because "text-center" is being applied last and all styling is applied via class-names (so no specificity issues), all styling contained in the "text-center" class should overwrite any previous styling.

In this case, the class "content-panel" contains `text-align: left;` but the "text-center" class is not overwriting this.

I checked just to be sure, but I'm not using `!important` declarations anywhere.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Works fine here: https://www.bootply.com/EdgEIAVfdF. Please edit your question to include a [mcve]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It goes off the order in the CSS file if it's just the class on its own.

For example this one with the text center first won't apply it:

```css
.text-center {
text-align: center;
}

.content-panel {
text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-panel inline-panel text-center">
    Some text
</div>
```

Whereas this one will because it's last in the CSS order:

```css
.content-panel {
text-align: left;
}

.text-center {
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-panel inline-panel text-center">
    Some text
</div>
```

One thing you could try is increasing the specificity of the CSS, so `.text-center` would become something like `.content-panel.text-center`, that should override the left alignment.

Comment: That's most likely it, since our external libraries are bundled and injected before our own stylesheets are also mixed in. IMHO, it shouldn't work that way since the classes have different names, but I guess that's life.